# SSRS expression for date difference to a number

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have this expression:

```
=COUNT(Fields!RecId.Value) - 
IIF(Fields!Status.Value="Assigned", 
    DATEDIFF("d", Fields!CreatedDateTime.Value,Fields!ResolvedDateTime.Value), 
    DATEDIFF("d", Fields!CreatedDateTime.Value,Fields!AssignedDateTime.Value)) 
- IIF(Weekday(Parameters!StartDate.Value, 1) = 1, 1, 0)
- IIF(Weekday(Parameters!StartDate.Value, 1) = 7, 1, 0)
- IIF(Weekday(Parameters!EndDate.Value, 1) = 1, 1, 0)
- IIF(Weekday(Parameters!EndDate.Value, 1) = 7, 1, 0)
```

What I want to be able to return is the RecID value minus the date difference if the date is more than 1 day.

Comment: So it's working now but you just want to add a check for the Date Difference used being greater than 1? What do you want to show if the difference is only 1 day?

Comment: It is working but the values it returns is not correct.  For example, I have accepted 5 tasks of those tasks I accepted 4 out of the 5 within one day.  The way my output should be is 4.  I want to show the total RedId minus the the recid over one day.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment, it seems like you want the count of records minus the number of records where the work days between the Created Date and if Status is "Assigned" the Resolved Date else the Assigned Date.

```
=COUNT(Fields!RecId.Value) - 
SUM(
    IIF(Fields!Status.Value = "Assigned", 
        IIF(DATEDIFF("d", Fields!CreatedDateTime.Value, Fields!ResolvedDateTime.Value)
        - (DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!CreatedDateTime.Value, Fields!ResolvedDateTime.Value)*2)
        - (IIF(WEEKDAY(Fields!CreatedDateTime.Value) = 7, 1, 0)
        - (IIF(WEEKDAY(Fields!ResolvedDateTime.Value) = 6, 1, 0)) 
        - 1) > 1, 0, 1)
        , 
        IIF(DATEDIFF("d", Fields!CreatedDateTime.Value, Fields!AssignedDateTime.Value) > 1, 0, 1)
        - (DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!CreatedDateTime.Value, Fields!AssignedDateTime.Value) * 2)
        - (IIF(WEEKDAY(Fields!CreatedDateTime.Value) = 7, 1, 0)
        - (IIF(WEEKDAY(Fields!AssignedDateTime.Value) = 6, 1, 0)) 
        - 1) > 1, 0, 1)
    )
```

Comment: That is working better, but the actual value is not showing correctly.  It is showing the number of tasks that are accepted in more than a day.  What I need it to show is the number of tasks that were accepted within a day.

Sum of Accepted     Total Tasks (Count of RecId)
1                               2  e.g. user accepted 2 tasks but one task was beyond one day
5                               5  e.g. user accepted 5 tasks and all were in one day

Comment: I am changing from an Excel workbook to SSRS.  The code for the excel workbook is as follows:
Days to Accept
=IF([@Status]="Forwarded",NETWORKDAYS([@CreatedDateTime],[@ResolvedDateTime]),NETWORKDAYS([@CreatedDateTime],[@AssignedDateTime]))
Accept<= One day: 
=IF([@[DAYS_To_Accept]]<=2,1,0)

Comment: I have updated the expression so that it now shows the number of records minus ones where the work days are 1 or less. It uses **Assigned** while your Excel has **Forwarded** tho...